# Problem saving multiple files to cloud storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

My problem appears only sometimes(what is really strange) while saving multiple files simultaneously to cloud storage. I am using [google-cloud/storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage) library version 6.9.5.
I was able to find out people having the same issue however none of their solutions worked for me(neither changing stream options nor applying timeout). Firstly I thought that bandwidth could be exceeded, however I am almost sure we are not saving over 50Gb of data(I tried to check it using cloud charts; however you can check bandwidth usage only if other services are using cloud storage - in my case i get "No data available").

For further explanation:
In my code there is a function called  "uploadFileToGCS" which is invoked around 57 times per each process. Process includes saving 35jpg(20KB per one) images, 1 tiff image(500KB) and 7 json(150KB per one) file. Simoultaneously 30 processes are invoked.

Here is exactly what error says(different files throw this error, sometimes jpg, sometimes json - there is no rule):

```js
error - unhandledRejection: FetchError: request to https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/satellite-photos/o?uploadType=multipart&name=64d162a80103b55f87a6cdb4_64db59204f7cd1f34a65e5c7_2023_6_31_raw.tiff failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (D:\WORK\nirby-project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\node-fetch\index.js:1:65756)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:496:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
```

function saving 5 images(which is invoked 7 times in the same time):

saveLayers.ts:

```js
import { saveSinglePhoto } from "~/helpers/sentinel/saveSinglePhoto";

interface INdviData {
   min: number;
   max: number;
   averageNDVI: number;
   buffer: Buffer;
}

const saveLayers = async (
   fileNameBase: string,
   trueColorData: Buffer,
   ndviData: INdviData,
   contrastNdviData: Buffer,
   sclData: Buffer,
   clmData: Buffer
) => {
   console.log(fileNameBase);

   const data = await Promise.all([
       saveSinglePhoto(trueColorData, fileNameBase, "TRUECOLOR"),
       saveSinglePhoto(ndviData.buffer, fileNameBase, "NDVI"),
       saveSinglePhoto(contrastNdviData, fileNameBase, "CONTRAST_NDVI"),
       saveSinglePhoto(sclData, fileNameBase, "SCL"),
       saveSinglePhoto(clmData, fileNameBase, "CLM"),
   ]);

   return data;
};

export default saveLayers;
```

saveSinglePhoto.ts

```js
import { SatelliteData } from "~/interfaces/sentinel/SatelliteData";
import uploadFileToGCS from "../gcs/uploadFileToGCS";

const baseUrl = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${process.env.GCLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET}/`;

export const saveSinglePhoto = async (
    buffer: Buffer,
    fileNameBase: string,
    layerId: string
): Promise<SatelliteData | null> => {
    const fileName = fileNameBase + layerId + ".jpg";

    await uploadFileToGCS(fileName, buffer, "image/jpeg");

    const satelliteData: SatelliteData = {
        layerId: layerId,
        fileUrl: baseUrl + fileName,
    };

    return satelliteData;
};
```

uploadFileToGCS.ts

```js
import { Storage } from "@google-cloud/storage";

const gcsKey = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(process.env.GCLOUD_CRED_FILE, "base64").toString());

const storage = new Storage({
    credentials: {
        client_email: gcsKey.client_email,
        private_key: gcsKey.private_key,
    },
    projectId: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID,
});

const uploadFileToGCS = (filename: string, data: any, contentType: string) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const file = storage.bucket(process.env.GCLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET).file(filename);

        const stream = file.createWriteStream({
            metadata: {
                contentType,
            },
            resumable: false,
            validation: false,
            timeout: 86400,
        });

        stream.on("error", (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });

        stream.on("finish", () => {
            resolve("ok");
        });

        stream.end(data);
    });
};

export default uploadFileToGCS;
```

**=======EDIT========**

Cloud tasks seems to be a solution for my problem - however my server stucks while invoking **createTask** - I get no response, everything is freezed

```js
import { v2beta3 } from "@google-cloud/tasks";
import { google } from "@google-cloud/tasks/build/protos/protos";

const client = new v2beta3.CloudTasksClient();

const project = process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID;
const location = process.env.GCLOUD_QUEUE_LOCATION;
const queue = process.env.GCLOUD_QUEUE_NAME;

const parent = client.queuePath(project, location, queue);

const gcsKey = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(process.env.GCLOUD_CRED_FILE, "base64").toString());
const email = gcsKey.client_email;

const createUploadTask = async (filename: string, bucket: string, contentType: string, data: any) => {
    const payload = {
        filename,
        bucket,
        contentType,
        data,
    };

    const url = `${process.env.GCLOUD_FUNCTIONS_URL}/uploadToCS`;

    const task = {
        httpRequest: {
            httpMethod: google.cloud.tasks.v2beta3.HttpMethod.POST,
            url,
            oidcToken: {
                serviceAccountEmail: email,
                audience: url,
            },
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString("base64"),
        },
    };

    const [response] = await client.createTask({ parent, task });
    const name = response.name ?? "name not exists";

    return name;
};

export default createUploadTask;
```

Comment: Did you try to limit the connection concurrency? You should reach a limit for security/equity reasons.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere  Thank you! I was able to find this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency). But still I have a question:  What is the best way to limit the connection concurrency in my case? Is there a method to save few files at once using the same stream?
How to bypass the 1000 simultaneous request limit?

Comment: What your event source? What triggers your file uploads?

Comment: You can try leveraging a service like [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks) that allows you to queue up your requests and run them asynchronously with exponential backoff.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere My application is processing satellite data for farmlands. When user creates a field I need to fetch data from the latest 30 months. Approximetely there are 7 days per month which contain data - each day: 1 json and 5 jpgs and per whole month there is 1 tiff. So "Process" was a name for fetching month data. In my code there is an array(month + year in each index) which I use for forEach loop that invokes fetching data for every month.

Comment: @TheAddonDepot I am afraid that it won't suit my needs, because Cloud Tasks gives possibility to invoke a request one by one and it is not recommended solution for [interactive apps](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview) - I assume that each upload would take about 1 second so invoking 30*(1 + 35 + 7) = 1290 uploads will take a really long while and I need callback when it is finished. I have to be aware of this because I am saving a link to every uploaded file in db - so when I have a saved link I need to be sure that it leads to existing resource(so I applied resolve or reject)

Comment: @MichałDubrowski Cloud Tasks support parallel execution by default - so your uploads would be running concurrently (not one-by-one).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Indeed, Cloud Task is the correct service to use. Generate a list of download request and create a task for each of them. Each task call an endpoint (Your Cloud Run service) which will download the file. Control the rate limit of this endpoint call with Cloud Task configuration.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere @TheAddonDepot Really thanks for this advice. I did as I was told, however another problem occured - the code freezes on line:
```const [response] = await client.createTask({ parent, task });```
- I don't get any response even if tasks appear in queue. Please take a look on the post again, because I have added the whole create task function. 
Additionally I need to know when task is finished - however I'm afraid that invoking  "getTask" for as many times as I previously sent requests to cloud storage would lead me to the same problem with requests concurency limit.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere To be honest I'm not exactly sure how the solution with cloud tasks works - I'm still reaching the cloud more than 1k times simultaneously - so the concurrency request limit does not apply to cloud tasks? Is this limit only for cloud storage?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I am worry that I runned into the same problem with concurrent request limit but this time in the context of cloud tasks. Is there a different method to save multiple files - what about BigQuery - should I focus on that?

Comment: The rate limit of Cloud Task does not solve the issue? There might have an hot spot. Can you share the pattern of your file name?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere The pattern of saved file:
```${userId}_${fieldId}_${photoDate.getUTCFullYear()}_${photoDate.getUTCMonth()}_${photoDate.getUTCDate()}_{fileType}.{fileExtension}```
File type is one of the following: NDVI, CONTRAST_NDVI, TRUECOLOR, SCL,
CLM or ndviArray.
So example file name would be: 
64d162a80103b55f87a6cdb4_64e5f881a5701afa40b55c60_2023_3_24_TRUECOLOR.jpg

Comment: Could be an hotspot. Does your video help? https://youtu.be/l-XDw55qUzs?list=PLIivdWyY5sqJcBvDh5dfPoblLGhG1R1-O

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere this error is showing sometimes:
```err =  FetchError: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed, reason: socket hang up
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (D:\node-fetch\index.js:1:65756)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:520:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',```

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have to say that I use Next.js as backend. May it be the cause of the problems? Should I switch to Express.js or the whole thing is not connected with the kind of backend? Now I am using uuid as the name of the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to change my code to have an array of SatelliteFiles(file name + buffer + content type) and use [p-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-limit) library. Now I am uploading all files only in this one place in code.

This new approach allowed me to achieve similar results to this:

```
Number of files to upload:  186
All files uploaded to GCS:  207.94119999930263  ms
```

Here is my code for other people dealing with this problem:

```js
const downloadSatelliteFiles = async (files: SatelliteFile[]) => {
    const limit = pLimit(5);
    const promises: Promise<void>[] = [];

    files.forEach((file) => {
        promises.push(
            limit(() => {
                uploadFileToGCS(file.fileName, file.buffer, file.contentType);
            })
        );
    });

    await Promise.all(promises);

    return;
};

const uploadFileToGCS = (filename: string, data: any, contentType: string) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const file = storage.bucket(process.env.GCLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET).file(filename);

        const stream = file.createWriteStream({
            metadata: {
                contentType,
                cacheControl: "no-cache",
            },
            resumable: false,
        });
        stream.on("error", (err) => {
            console.log("UPLOAD_ERROR");
            console.log(err);
        });
        stream.on("finish", () => {
            resolve("ok");
        });
        stream.end(data);
    });
};
```